Which equivalence/congruence symbol is used to specify simplified notation?
What is the most common operator used when establishing an equivalence relationship e.g.
$x_t\color{red}{\equiv}x(\phi_t)$
whose purpose is to simplify notation in general terms, which can be useful in more elaborate expressions?
From Wikipedia's extensive list,
multiple symbols ($:=$, $\simeq$) seem to fit this particular context.

Why not $x_t:=x(\phi_t)$ as a shorthand definition? Because $a\color{red}{\equiv} b\bmod p$ already has a different meaning.

Yes, that would be one solution, I was wondering if there was any symbol used specifically for this purpose.

The shortest symbol here is the empty symbol, by saying "let us write $x_t$ for $x(\phi_t)$". This uses no symbol at all. Sometimes it is better to use words instead of symbols.
